# Are questions such as "What are important topics in machine learning right now?" acceptable on this forum?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I've posted two questions on the main website asking about important topics in machine learning. ([Important topics in machine learning right now](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232566/important-topics-in-machine-learning-right-now) & [Subjects in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232307/subjects-in-machine-learning/)) They have both been rejected, the first would be a duplicate and the second would be opinion-based.

The first one is *not* a duplicate, as someone else has pointed out in the comments. I asked to reopen it, no one has responded. The second one is, in my opinion, not opinion based either. It asks for what people come across frequently, not what they *think* they come across. Could anyone give me some advice on what to do? I've got a feeling that Cross Validated doesn't like these sorts of questions, but seeing as this website has lots of experienced professionals, it would in my opinion be silly to filter out these questions completely. Most questions on here blow my mind as I have near zero experience and I'd love to even get the gist of it, but right now that's kind of tough when you don't even know where to start.

Comment: There is good advice in the [help].

Comment: You can also check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They'd be good for Quora or Yahoo answers or somewhere like that—indeed see https://www.quora.com/What-are-currently-the-hot-topics-in-Machine-Learning-research-and-in-real-applications —but these rather soft questions that seem to invite anyone & everyone to add their two pennorth to an ever-growing number of answers aren't generally seen as being appropriate for Stack Exchange sites, which encourage a focus on specific, practical, problems that people face when doing & learning.

Comment: British to American translation: two pennorth = two pennyworth = two bits worth.

Comment: @NickCox, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_penn%27orth) suggests it's *two-cents worth*. '[Two bits](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_bits)' is 25 cents, or approximately the cost of a [shave and a haircut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxU-SgOtVSM) somewhere, at some point in history.

Comment: I am trying to translate on similar metaphorical meaning, not currency equivalent. Is two cents' worth used to mean my little contribution? I suggest that these are alternative translations. Tuppenceworth (to use yet another word) is not usually anything that you get for two pence.

Comment: @NickCox, Yes. '[Two cents worth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents)' means 'my thoughts on this (but they may not be exactly right)'. At any rate, the above was mostly meant as tongue in cheek.

Comment: @gung Thanks. I wasn't being entirely serious either.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that this kind of question would make a good Wiki post if the question is posed to the effect of: "based on the frequency of keywords in peer-reviewed ML journals, conference proceedings, respected magazine articles, etc., what are the most popular topics?"

Such a list could be constantly updated as topics of interest evolve and, IMO, would certainly be a service to the community since they can help inform about the state-of-the-art.

**EDIT**: incidentally, I just ran into a very interesting blog post from the folks at Mathworks that is close to what I was envisioning when I wrote this yesterday. See [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/08/08/text-mining-machine-learning-research-papers-with-matlab/)